# ORACLE : db migration from 11.1 - 12.1

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, sun, oracle12c

Below is my environment :

- sun-solaris , sparc machine
- rac setup
- oracle 11.1

I have a database with many users in it, from which I need to export a particular user data and import it to another machine, with the following configuration:

- sun-solaris , sparc machine
- rac setup
- oracle 12.1

I don't want to perform full database export/import due to few constraints. If I am doing a particular user export/import, what are things I need to do manually like create users, tablespaces and grant permissions, etc, before importing the database? Also how do I know what are the permissions I need to give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both of the versions you have Oracle Data pump:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm

If you don't have any types you created - it would work just fine,
if you do have-  you'll have to manually check everything works correctly.

just export using data-pump the user (the SCHEMAS parameters) - and from my experience - it will export the user fine.
note this : "Cross-schema references are not exported unless the referenced schema is also specified in the list of schemas to be exported" - this might be what you referred to.

I recommend creating an export of Metadata only, and copying the data on a DB_LINK.

good luck